# Websocket connection between two servers

Tags: python-2.7, websocket, tornado

Im using python tornado as web server and I have a backend server and a frontend server. I want to create browser-frontend-backend  connection. Can anyone help me how to do this? I know how to create websocket connection between frontend and browser but I have no idea how to connect my frontend server to backend server to stream realtime data parsed by my backend server.

Answer (score 2):

It looks tornado had an ability to also operate as a [websocket client](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/websocket.html#client-side-support).  Perhaps you could use this with your front end server acting as a client to the backend server.

Answer (score 0):

WebSocket was designed for low-latency bidirectional browser<->service communication. It's placed on top of TCP/IP and brings along some overhead. It was designed to solve all the problems that you simply do not have when it's about front-end<->back-end communication, because there we're talking about a defined environment which is under your control. Hence, I would recommend going back to the basics and do simple TCP/IP communication between your front-end and back-end.

Comment: I need to stream data from backend to client/browser and I cant stream directly from backend to client for security reasons, therefore I need my frontend server to make a socket connection to the backend to stream data. backend(live data)<->frontend(web-interface server)<->client(browser). Sorry I'm new to programming and server architectures.

Comment: Yes, and this is what I am saying: backend(live data)<-basic TCP/IP ->frontend(web-interface server)<-WebSocket->client(browser)